# Remove duplicates which spans multiple lines

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, python-3.x

Please help me resolve issue.
I have a large text file and i have to remove duplicate lines.
The problem is that sometimes the duplication spans multiple lines
For example first two lines is unique and they repeat three times. 
I have to remove this pairs of repeated lines.
I must delete duplicates only if they appear one after another.
The condition is met before the appearance of some other lines,
it means that we have to start again checking count of unique lines which will be repeated.

**TEST DATA**

Test line 1
Test line 2
Test line 1
Test line 2
Test line 1
Test line 2

Some other lines
  
...............................

Test line 1
Test line 2
Test line 3

Some other lines
  
...............................

Test line 1
Test line 2
Test line 3
Test line 1
Test line 2
Test line 3
Test line 1
Test line 2
Test line 3

Some other lines
  
...............................

Test line 1
Test line 1
Test line 1

Some other lines
  
...............................

Test line 1
Test line 2
Test line 3
Test line 4
Test line 1
Test line 2
Test line 3
Test line 4

Some other lines
  
...............................

**Expected result**

Test line 1
Test line 2

Some other lines
  
...............................

Test line 1
Test line 2
Test line 3

Some other lines
  
...............................

Test line 1
Test line 2
Test line 3

Some other lines
  
...............................

Test line 1

Some other lines
  
...............................

Test line 1
Test line 2
Test line 3
Test line 4

Some other lines
  
...............................

Jim Mischel thanks for clarifying my question. I understood that i made example which is not easy to understand. I know we can use set for filtering , but it is not what i need. 
**I NEED - Remove adjacent duplicate lines and sequences of lines.** 
I am trying to change `1,1` into `1`, and `1,2,1,2,1,2` into `1,2`, but `1,2,3,1,2` wouldn't be changed. 
Please *note* that count of repeated lines can be different.
It can be `1,2,1,2,1,2` into `1,2` or `1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3` into `1,2,3` or `1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4` into `1,2,3,4`

Comment: Those who would answer "just use sets," please read the question and study the examples. He's not asking to remove duplicate lines, but rather *adjacent* duplicate lines and sequences of lines. So he's trying to change `1,1` into `1`, and `1,2,1,2,1,2` into `1,2`, but `1,2,3,1,2` wouldn't be changed.

Comment: Sets are a built-in feature of python, it is not going to solve the problem because this is a logic problem which can be resolved by coding correctly, I'm not going to answer this because I'm not doing your work, but using sets may be a useful tool.

Answer (score 2):

Use regex to reduce the multiple line repeats to singletons:

```
import sys
import re

string = sys.stdin.read()

# use pattern matching to reduce the repeated line sequences:
# ie. does a line look like the one that follows it; does a 
# pair of lines look like the pair that follow them; etc.
string = re.sub(r"((?:^.*\n)+)(?=\1)", "", string, flags=re.MULTILINE)

sys.stdout.write(string)
```

**INPUT**

```
Test line 1
Test line 2
Test line 1
Test line 2
Test line 1
Test line 2

Some other lines 1
...............................

Test line 1
Test line 2
Test line 3

Some other lines 2
...............................

Test line 1
Test line 2
Test line 3
Test line 1
Test line 2
Test line 3
Test line 1
Test line 2
Test line 3

Some other lines 3
...............................

Test line 1
Test line 1
Test line 1

Some other lines 4
...............................

Test line 1
Test line 2
Test line 3
Test line 4
Test line 1
Test line 2
Test line 3
Test line 4

Some other lines 5
...............................
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Test line 1
Test line 2

Some other lines 1
...............................

Test line 1
Test line 2
Test line 3

Some other lines 2
...............................

Test line 1
Test line 2
Test line 3

Some other lines 3
...............................

Test line 1

Some other lines 4
...............................

Test line 1
Test line 2
Test line 3
Test line 4

Some other lines 5
...............................
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. This was really useful to slim down recurring stack traces in logs!

Comment: This is very useful, but I wish it was explained it a bit more. As it is it is a complete black box to me.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid duplicates you can use sets:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,3,2,1,2,4]
>>> set(l)
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

You just need to identify "some other lines" to start queuing lines in the list.

Comment: That's not going to solve the problem. Re-read the question and study the examples.

Answer (score -2):

You can use SET

```
list_of_lines = ["line 1", "line 2", "line 3", "line 1", "line 2"]
list_of_lines = list(set(list_of_lines))
```

Or you can add your lines in set.

```
list_of_lines = set()
set.add("line 1")
set.add("line 2")
set.add("line 3")
```

it will automatically remove duplicates

Comment: That's not going to solve the problem. Re-read the question and study the examples.